# Are Labradors predisposed to ear infections?

Tags: dogs, health, infections, ears-nose-throat

I would like to know if ear infections are more common in large dog breeds; chiefly in Labrador Retrievers, likely owing to their hanging ears and inherently small ear canals.

Mine is scratching, rubbing at the ears and head shaking only recently.

Comment: I have had 3 labs and yes they get more ear infections. Their ears lay flat.  A large breed like a dobernam then no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floppy ears tend to catch water, which results in more infections. Our vet taught us to dry out our dog's ears with gauze, and there's a few commercial options for regularish ear cleaning.

Floppy ears are adorable, but a little more work and its worth bringing the dog to the vet for a proper examination and basic cleaning if you suspect infection

Answer (score 2):

Not that I've heard about.  We have one and wasn't especially warned about it, although it is advised to periodically inspect and sniff at your dog's ears.

Is there any reason why you're especially concerned about this?